# What is the proper way of creating documentation in .NET (or general)?

Tags: c#, .net, rider

I am just starting my professional career with software development and I got first project to get to know with it.

What very suprised me, was the fact ~30% of code are actually comments with

```
<param name="">
<summary>
```

and so on. I think .NET devs know what I mean.

The point is, it is making this code very ugly. I understand it helps Swagger to make documentation, it helps IDE to describe methods and their params, but... it also makes code ugly.

Is it common practice? Or can it be done diffrent way?

BTW, I know it can be hidden in IDE, but this is not what I am asking about.

Comment: Just to give you an example... check [Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,06d13c9cb8b83f5d)

Comment: For sure you are all right. What I was thinking was to write a code in the way it doesn't need or need very little comments. Ofc I know comments are ignored by compiler:D

Comment: @Lucas The only code that doesn't need comments is code that you don't need. Even if something is very clear in _how_ it does something, it may not be telling you _why_. Comments can.

Comment: Allright, I think I am convienced. Thank you all guys.

Comment: If you live in the corporate world, you use whatever scheme they have decided on.  If you're working on a collaborative code base, you just conform to whatever the group is doing.  You aren't likely to have a choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to give you an example... check [Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,06d13c9cb8b83f5d).

Documentation is necessary and it looks ugly to others if you don't do it. Understandable/maintainable code is good code for everyone.

You cannot go away from it and you must not.

Comment: Wow! Nice link you gave here. I didn't know it even existed!

Answer (score 0):

Including documentation comments in code as shown below is the preferred way to write documentation. Following this approach, developers can read the documentation in their IDEs or an HTML version can be generated for the web.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// An effective trap for capturing delicious, tasty roadrunners.
/// </summary>
public class RoadrunnerTrap
{
}
```

With that said, you can also name your classes, variables, and methods clearly to begin with and avoid having to write as much documentation. Not having documentation is usually bad but too much obvious or repetitive documentation is worse.